# Apache, lighttpd, nginx, cherokee, what's the best combination?

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver, lighttpd, cherokee

I have a blog, dynamic (php) and static content (images, css, js). I googled a lot to find benchmarks on each server and figured out that there's actually no best server. Therefore I'm looking for returns on experience to choose the good combination.

**Update in response to wheaties**: well, my needs are I think, the same as everyone; I need all my pages to load quickly--including static content--an I need the highest HTTP queries/second rate possible. Also, if it can help, I'm using MongoDB. Btw, do I still need to cache my DB queries with this?

Comment: What do you need?  What are your requirements?  Where are the bottlenecks in your system?  Before adding complexity can you describe those things first?  Otherwise, you don't know what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Apache and Nginx:

I used Apache for almost 10 years. Then I discovered Nginx. 
Quickly I found Nginx appealing

- simple and powerful C code
- configuration syntax is intuitive and elegant
- Nginx was built with performance and efficiency in mind. It *is* incredibly efficient, even with thousands of connections.
- `php-fpm` works well with Nginx

So, I would recommend, *between the two* (Apache and Nginx), Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Lighttpd is well known for serving static content. Nginx is a good option for dynamic (php) pages. I've heard of few sites which use lighttpd only for serving static content.

Answer (score 0):

Lighttpd for static content and some caching scripts for dynamic (PHP).